# Python Sockets connection actively refused by target machine

Tags: python, connection, python-sockets

When trying to create a python sockets server, I succeded in sending messages over my local network. However, when trying to use my public IP address, I get an error saying that the target machine has actively refused the connection on the server side.

I have some questions:

- What is the 'target machine'?
- Why is it refusing to connect?
- How can I solve this so I can send messages to my server from any device connected to the internet?

I have tried to solve this by changing the port and trying different IP addresses from `ipconfig` as well as ipinfo.io. None of these attempts solved my problem. If there is any way you can help, please do!

Here is my server code:

```
import socket 
import threading

class Colour:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


HEADER = 64
PORT = 2345
SERVER = "__.__.___.___"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "/disconnect"


server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.connect(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connected = False

            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            conn.send(f"{Colour.OKCYAN}Msg succesfully recieved by server{Colour.ENDC}".encode(FORMAT))

    conn.close()
        

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

Comment: How did you try to connect the Python server (program, script)? How is the client machine connected to the server machine or is it the same? Operating system (seems Linux)?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Windows and I'm running the client and server on the same machine but I get the error the second I start the server so I can't connect the client

Comment: Show the code you use for the server as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: "target machine" is the machine you're connecting to in `socket.connect()`.

Comment: Make sure the firewall on the server allows the incoming connection.

Comment: I tried socket.bind instead but that returnsOSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context (i'm using a public IP)

Comment: How do I check that? (firewall)

Comment: Are you connected directly to Internet or through a router (more exactly through a network address translation firewall)?

Comment: My computer is connected with ethernet to my internet router

Comment: Such routers normally use a NAT firewall (at least for IPv4). In this case the public IP address is actually the address of the router and your PC can't bind to this address. Instead you can bind to your LAN address (usually something like ´192.168.___.___´) and configure the router so that accesses to the public IP and a particular port are redirected to the LAN address and the designated port on the PC. This may make your system less secure.

Comment: This is rather dissapointing as I can't really mess with my router. Thank you though for the answer.